# Recreating Accord.NET DecisionTree website example - Given keys not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, accord.net

I am following the example on the Accord.net website to the letter:

[Link to the example, scroll to the bottom](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_Learning_ID3Learning.htm)

My code is a copy of the code on the website example. I have the correct NuGet packages included.

```
  DataTable data = new DataTable("Mitchell's Tennis Example");

                data.Columns.Add("Day", "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");

                data.Rows.Add("D1", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No");
                data.Rows.Add("D2", "Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No");
                data.Rows.Add("D3", "Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D4", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D5", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D6", "Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "No");
                data.Rows.Add("D7", "Overcast", "Cool", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D8", "Sunny", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "No");
                data.Rows.Add("D9", "Sunny", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D10", "Rain", "Mild", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D11", "Sunny", "Mild", "Normal", "Strong", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D12", "Overcast", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D13", "Overcast", "Hot", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes");
                data.Rows.Add("D14", "Rain", "Mild", "High", "Strong", "No");

                // Create a new codification codebook to 
                // convert strings into integer symbols
                Codification codebook = new Codification(data);

                // Translate our training data into integer symbols using our codebook:
                DataTable symbols = codebook.Apply(data);
                int[][] inputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind");
                int[] outputs = symbols.ToArray<int>("PlayTennis");

                // Gather information about decision variables
                DecisionVariable[] attributes =
    {
      new DecisionVariable("Outlook",     3), // 3 possible values (Sunny, overcast, rain)
      new DecisionVariable("Temperature", 3), // 3 possible values (Hot, mild, cool)  
      new DecisionVariable("Humidity",    2), // 2 possible values (High, normal)    
      new DecisionVariable("Wind",        2)  // 2 possible values (Weak, strong) 
    };

                int classCount = 2; // 2 possible output values for playing tennis: yes or no

                //Create the decision tree using the attributes and classes
                DecisionTree tree = new DecisionTree(attributes, classCount);

                // Create a new instance of the ID3 algorithm
                ID3Learning id3learning = new ID3Learning(tree);

                // Learn the training instances!
                id3learning.Run(inputs, outputs);

                string answer = codebook.Translate("PlayTennis",
                    tree.Compute(codebook.Translate("Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong")));

                Console.WriteLine("Calculate for: Sunny, Hot, High, Strong");
                Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer);
```

I get this exception:

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

At this line of code:

```
string answer = codebook.Translate("PlayTennis",
                tree.Compute(codebook.Translate("Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong")));
```

Where do I start to solve this? I've checked the codebook in the debugger and it contains elements like it should.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Instead of creating the dictionary as "Codification codebook = new Codification(data);", create it as "Codification codebook = new Codification(data, "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");" passing the columns explicitly. I will update the documentation.

Comment: I would recommend posting an answer instead of a comment. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the framework documentation was slightly outdated. Instead of creating the dictionary as

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(data);
```

the framework now expects the user to pass the columns of interest in the Codification's constructor. Thus the Codification dictionary should now be created as

```
Codification codebook = new Codification(data, 
    "Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind", "PlayTennis");
```

The documentation will be rebuilt in a few days!